# Pass clipboard to batch in Windows XP

Tags: command-line, windows-xp, batch-file, cmd

Using Windows XP I want to copy text (URL) to the clipboard and then run a batch file that will use that URL.

I know the reverse is possible with the clip.exe floating around.

Answer (score 1):

I use my own `CLIPTEXT` program. It is a very simple 5-lines pascal, here is the source code. I am sure that you can get the idea and translate it to any other language.

```
program cliptext;
uses clipbrd;
begin
  writeln(clipboard.asText);  
end.
```

then, in your batch files, you may use to start the copied URLs.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%c in ('cliptext') do start "" "%%c"
```

Comment: ye, i wrote a small python script to the same end.