# Accessing copied text from a clipboard and store in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

In the batch file that I am creating, I am trying to make a string comparison between two different copied text. Basically, is the old copied text the same as the newer copied text. For this I want to access the clipboard and store the old copied text in a variable inside my batch file. Then, copy the new text, store it in another variable inside my batch file, and compare the two and see if they are the same. I have tried searching for a solution, but all the articles that I have seen describe how to copy text into the clipboard using a batch file. Whereas, I am trying to do the opposite. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: in batch you can use swiss file knife (SFK)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15747067/1683264) for a way to retrieve text from the clipboard with a batch script.  It will use PowerShell if available, or .NET otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short and batch embed solution:

1) create a small VB file which store the content of the clipboard in a temporary file

```
set clipFile=%temp%\clipboard
set vbFile=%temp%\clipboard.vbs
del %vbFile% %clipFile%

rem Create VB file
>"%vbFile%" (
echo.Set objHTML = CreateObject("htmlfile"^)
echo.ClipboardText = objHTML.ParentWindow.ClipboardData.GetData("text"^)
echo.path = "%clipFile%"
echo.Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^)
echo.Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(path, 2, true^)
echo.objFile.WriteLine ClipboardText
echo.objFile.Close )>>"%vbFile%"
```

2) execute the VB script

```
"%vbFile%"
```

3) store file content in a variable

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    for /f "delims=" %%i in (%clipFile%) do Set line=%%i
    set clipboard=!line!
    echo clipboard="%clipboard%"
ENDLOCAL
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no native batch solution to read from the clipboard but there are some simple approaches using other languages.

Here's a Powershell script (which is easy to call from a batch file if you need to):  http://poshcode.org/2150

Raymond Chen has a solution using perl:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/11/10/9919908.aspx

Comment: And as a bonus, you can run Perl from within a batch file.