# Copy to clipboard using Bash for Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How do I copy results from the commandline directly to the clipboard?

On Windows's cmd.exe I can do simply `echo "asd" | clip` and it pipes output to the clipboard.

I tried to install `xclip` for that, and though it compiled, when called it prints:

```
Error: Can't open display: (null)
```

Using mouse is not the solution.

Comment: Is using the mouse an option? If so, just highlight the text.

Comment: Definitely not, I googled and saw many suggestions like that :)

Comment: For users familiar with `xclip` that combines copy and paste then you might be interested in the [paste command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819814/how-can-you-get-the-clipboard-contents-with-a-windows-command).

Answer (score 95, accepted):

In Build 14393 or later, if you want to copy something to clipboard in WSL console, just add '.exe' to what you do in Windows cmd.

```
echo "aaa"|clip.exe
```

To read from clipboard:

```
powershell.exe -command "Get-Clipboard"
```

Comment: Cool, works out of the box after upgrading to WSL/Ubuntu 16!

Comment: `echo` didn't work for me, but `cat` did. That is, entering `cat filePath | clip.exe` in the command prompt.

Comment: this works from shell to clipboard, but is there a solution for the reverse? looking for `pbpaste` or `xclip -o` equivalent.

Comment: @JetBlue Sounds like you were using echo wrong, then -- echo just prints the text you give it to the output. `cat` reads a file.

Comment: Something strange happens when I try to use io redirection with the read from clipboard option. I can run it just fine and it will dump the clipboard contents into the command line just fine, but when I try to do e.g. `powershell.exe -command "Get-Clipboard" > test.txt`, my WSL window appears to lose all personalization settings (font size, typeface) except color scheme. Is this typical?

Answer (score 8):

In order to copy non-ascii characters (other languages), I had to do this:

echo 'αβψδεφγ' | iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16le | clip.exe

utf-16le excludes the preceeding BOM so you can paste it back

Comment: I'm unable to run PowerShell scripts on my computer, so I had created a bash script instead. I tried running PowerShell from within the bash script but failed to get the results I wanted, and this solution was the only one that worked.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I created an alias for this in my WSL `~/.bashrc` file:

`alias clip='iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16le | clip.exe'`

Now I can pipe output to it like `echo 'αβψδεφγ' | clip`

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed to get this working on Cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to have something more 'easy' to use, you can add the commands from @reker to your ~/.bashrc file (if you use zsh, you have to put it in the ~/.zshrc file).

I added these two lines to my file:

```
alias paste="powershell.exe -command \"Get-Clipboard\""
function clip { "$1" | clip.exe;}
```

I use clip as a function, so I can use the command linux like ('command' 'use this for command'). If you would prefer the alias way, you can add something like

```
alias clip=clip.exe
```

than you don't have to write the .exe all the time.

Don't forget to run the command

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

after you saved the file. Otherwise the changes are only applied after a restart of your console.

Comment: I was looking strictly for copying the output of a command as I do that a lot. I never used a paste using command (I always just do shift+insert). But that's a nice suggestion, thanks!

Comment: There are a few bugs.So you can't copy&paste a path when there is a whitespace in it (using pwd). It doesn't escape them.

Answer (score 0):

This still does not seem to be supported: [Can Bash on Windows interact with the system clipboard?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/4gwnom/can_bash_on_windows_interact_with_the_system/).

A clever workaround is the open source tool [plak](https://github.com/sander/plak).