# Copy Clipboard Value to Variable and Append to Existing Text

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is there a way to assign the clipboard value to a variable, then append the variable to new text with a batch file?

Here is a copy of what I'm attempting to do. In my example, "world" represents the value that the clipboard contains.

```
@echo off
set myclip=world
(
   echo hello %myclip%
)| clip
```

Comment: There are 3rd party solutions see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17819928/4304 -or- if you can use powershell, there is a Get-Clipboard command.

Comment: Final Solution based on npocmaka's answer.  ``for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%i in (`mshta "javascript:Code(close(new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write(clipboardData.getData('Text'))));"``) `do set "clipboardText=%%i"

echo %clipboardText%
echo|set/p=%clipboardText% It WORKS!|clip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the clipboard data you can use this:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%i in (`mshta "javascript:Code(close(new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write(clipboardData.getData('Text'))));"`) do set "clipboardText=%%i"

echo %clipboardText%
```

Comment: I tried the code you provided, but it does not seem to work. Does mshta need to be running before batch is executed?

Comment: @crjunk - No. Is there any kind of error? I've just copied and pasted the code and it works form - prints the clipboard data on the console...

Comment: Wow.  We use Sentinel One at work for threat protection.  As soon as I executed the code it stopped the script and deleted it. Regardless of that I did see it echo the clipboard text.

Comment: It's displaying "%%i was unexpected at this time." when I add Pause to the script

Comment: @crjunk - execute this from bat file , but not from console directly. If you intend to use this from the console use single `%` instead of double.

Comment: Strange that it continued to give me that error after recreating the file multipe times. I ran it as a bat file each time. Now it is working properly. Maybe an odd character was pasted into the file and caused issues??  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using `Powershell -command "Get-Clipboard"`:

```
@echo off

for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%i in (`powershell -command "Get-Clipboard"`) do set "myclip=%%i"

echo hello %myclip%

pause
```