# Paste of clipboard to text file with batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to save the text that I copied from somewhere else in the text file with Batch file. To do this, I use the following code. But unfortunately I receive an empty text file! Do you have a solution to this problem?

```
@echo off 
echo Hello!> test.txt
paste > test.txt
```

Comment: Are you referring to this [paste](https://www.c3scripts.com/tutorials/msdos/paste.html) command? There is no `paste` in the standard Windows programs. There is `clip.exe` which copies text **to** the [system] clipboard. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819814/how-can-you-get-the-clipboard-contents-with-a-windows-command