# Turn clipboard into a variable inside a batch file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

First let me insist on the fact that I am completely new to batch coding, I have seen some code over the years and am used to using cmd, but never really delved into trying to accomplish complex tasks in a batch by myself.

So, basically I would like to copy some text to the clipboard (usernames, so will never exceed one line), then simply double clicking on a batch file to create a folder with that username and a few other tasks that aren't relevant here.

Anyway, I've got that second part down (with the username in question hardcoded in the batch), but not the clipboard to variable part.

I have read this thread :
[Access clipboard in Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832203/access-clipboard-in-windows-batch-file/27277546#27277546)

And especially rojo's answer which is very interesting. The solution I'm interested in is the "Update 2" one, with one line of code using Powershell:

```
powershell -sta "add-type -as System.Windows.Forms; [windows.forms.clipboard]::GetText()"
```

However, there are a few issues with me using it:

- I learned the existence of powershell reading this, so I don't really know how to decipher the code, and turning it into a variable that I could use later in other lines.
- I'm using Windows 10 so I believe powershell is on my computer, however I have no idea if using that line would be allowed in a normal batch file?

Anyway, first I want to thank rojo for his solutions, they are great and I will continue searching for a way to resolve my problem, and also thanks to anyone that would be willing to help me understand and hopefully resolve this!

Comment: The line runs a PowerShell command to output the text currently in the clipboard. Yes, you can run the line from a batch script. Finding that out by actually running the line from a test batch file would probably have taken less than half the time posting this question took.

Comment: [Refael Ackemann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28580546/6811411) to your referenced question shows a cmd line solution, in a batch double the percent signs.

Comment: Thank you LotPings, that post had eluded me. I stumbled a little but finally managed to get exactly the behavior I wanted, thanks!