# Is there a way in python or vbscript or .bat to copy text from clipboard and write to a file in utf-8 encoding?

Tags: python, windows, vbscript, batch-file, clipboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I read text from the (windows) clipboard from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101128/how-do-i-read-text-from-the-windows-clipboard-from-python)

Is there a way in python or vb or .bat to copy text from clipboard and write to a file in utf-8 encoding?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101128/how-do-i-read-text-from-the-windows-clipboard-from-python

Comment: Related posts regarding batch script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832203/access-clipboard-in-windows-batch-file  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704455/how-to-pass-clipboard-to-batch-in-xp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128463/use-clipboard-from-vbscript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct access to the clipboard without third-party COM objects.  You can use a workaround to get its contents.

```
' Grab the contents of the clipboard
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Navigate("about:blank")
strClipboard = objIE.document.parentwindow.clipboardData.GetData("text")
objIE.Quit
```

You can read more about this in my article [Scripting the Clipboard Contents in WSH](http://www.nilpo.com/2007/08/windows-xp/scripting-the-clipboard-contents-in-wsh/).

Once you have the contents, you can employ the help of .Net to encode it.

```
Set Encoder = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding") 
strClipboardB = Encoder.GetBytes_4(strClipboard) 'get bytes
Set Encoder = Nothing
```

I should warn you, I've never tested the clipboard method with UTF8 text.  It *should* work, but I'm not sure off the top of my head how that class handles UTF8 characters.